# flattenChildren(...) Reactjs warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a problem with updating data to google firebase

This is the constructor and handle function:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    done: false
  }
 this.handleDoneChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    done: event.target.checked
  })
  Firebase.database().ref('/items').child(this.props.item.key).update(
    {
      done: event.target.checked
    }
  );
};
```

}

and the rendered html

```
<input type="checkbox"
                 checked={this.state.done}
                 onChange={this.handleDoneChange}/>
```

Whenever I check/uncheck the box it gives me a warning

```
warning.js:44 Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `.$-KJ1NOzrpaa5HmjRPulQ`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.
```

but data are changed on firebase

Anyone have any idea of what is happening right here ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your render funciton

Comment: `render() {
return (
   <div>
     <input type="checkbox"
                 checked={this.state.done}
                 onChange={this.handleDoneChange}/>
   </div>
)}
`

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any problem with the above code. If you remove the google firebase code do you still get the error? Do you have any other component that maps the items from the firebase db? Trying looking at the callstack of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this if, it can help anyone for future reference.
My mistake was in this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    Firebase.database().ref('/items').on("value", function (data) {
      this.setState({
        listOfItems: []
      });
      console.log(this.state.listOfItems)
      for (let key of Object.keys(data.val())) {
        this.setState({
          listOfItems: this.state.listOfItems.concat({key: key, text: data.val()[key].text, done: data.val()[key].done})
        })
      }

    }.bind(this));

  }
```

Since Google Firebase uses websocket and any change on UI is manifested on the database so it tries to add every time same thing from the code

```
this.setState({
      listOfItems: this.state.listOfItems.concat({key: key, text: data.val()[key].text, done: data.val()[key].done})
    })
```

So I came with a different solution and there is no error on adding/updating/removing data:

```
componentDidMount() {
  Firebase.database().ref('/items').on("value", function (data) {
    let list = [];
    for (let key of Object.keys(data.val())) {
      let item = data.val()[key];
      item.key = key;
      list.push(item);
    }
    this.setState({
      listOfItems: list
    })
  }.bind(this));
}
```